# Can we Verify Contents on the browser PDF print in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I need to verify PDF contents, when I click on pdf print button on web page, it displays PDF to print. How can I verify? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium does not provide any API to verify the contents of a pdf. I am not sure which language binding you are using. However every
language has its own specific libraries that help you achieve parsing/extracting contents of pdf. 
e.g. In Java you might consider using pdfbox or iText.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/

https://developers.itextpdf.com/

Comment: I am Using Java

Comment: As mentioned you can think of using apache pdfbox or itext

Comment: Additionally, you could looking for using rest assured instead (or complementing) Selenium, since your goal is to check the response body, instead of the interaction of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Capture a screenshot of PDF and compare it with expected image.
Article linked here implements image comparison

[http://automationtesting.in/image-comparison-in-selenium/#:~:text=Practically%20speaking%20image%20comparison%20is,use%20to%20compare%20two%20images](http://automationtesting.in/image-comparison-in-selenium/#:%7E:text=Practically%20speaking%20image%20comparison%20is,use%20to%20compare%20two%20images).

Download PDF as a file and compare it with expected file.
Article linked here implements Comparing Pdf files With Selenium
[https://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-web-driver-menu/selenium-test-automation-with-java/165-comparing-pdf-documentations-with-selenium#:~:text=Testing%20approach%3A%20use%20Selenium%20Web,two%20packages%20as%20highlighted%20below](https://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-web-driver-menu/selenium-test-automation-with-java/165-comparing-pdf-documentations-with-selenium#:%7E:text=Testing%20approach%3A%20use%20Selenium%20Web,two%20packages%20as%20highlighted%20below).

Also check the link to a question `Is there a way to compare content of two text files using selenium?`  It may not be directly relevant but may provide context on comparing two artifacts.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527457/is-there-a-way-to-compare-content-of-two-text-files-using-selenium